# How could I connect 2 computer via USB-Serial adapter (2x FT232)

Tags: linux, usb, debian, kernel, serial

First time asking a question (if I'm not at the right place, feel free to point me to the right place) :)

I want to access PC2 with PC1 via two FT232 adapter.
Example:
[image]
I already tried to pass the console=ttyUSB0 argument to the kernel, mentioned here https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s03.en.html (see grub config below) however it does not seem to work (I only get a blinking cursor on the monitor connected to PC2 and no output on the serial monitor on PC1, both are set at 9600 bps) (both PC are running Debian 11 with the kernel 5.10.0-15)

tldr: trying to get a shell on a client connected to a server via ft232 ttl serial adapter

```
content of: /etc/default/grub

GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyUSB0,9600n8"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: What version of GRUB are you using?  Have you tried the settings at https://docs.stg.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-GRUB_2_over_a_Serial_Console.html ?  If both systems are up, and you use a terminal emulator on each side, can they talk to each other?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be super simple, all I had to do was to:

- setup /dev/ttyUSB0 on both computer
- Run the commands on the server

(Run with sudo or as root)

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
```

- BOOM, you got a login prompt and a shell

Ps: thanks davigo for the help and have a good day :]